# Sliding Drawer with ActionBarCompat

Tags: android, android-actionbar, slidingdrawer, android-actionbar-compat

When I use ActionBarCompat then Sliding Drawer is not working ..and same drawer working using ActionBarSherlock..but i want to use ActionBarCompat in my app..is it possible with Sliding Drawer..?

Comment: Yes its possible. Check example: [Creating a Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)